# Convert Binance String To object for reaching each member of object

Tags: node.js, string, object

In Nodejs i have a Binace returned string like this :

content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\ncontent-length: 312\r\nconnection: close\r\ndate: Wed, 12 May 2021 08:02:40 GMT\r\nserver: nginx\r\nvary: Accept-Encoding\r\nx-mbx-uuid: b2bee016-a506-46cc-9bb1-1d04eee4666f\r\nx-mbx-used-weight: 81\r\nx-mbx-used-weight-1m: 81\r\nx-mbx-order-count-10s: 1\r\nx-mbx-order-count-1d: 6\r\nstrict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains\r\nx-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nx-xss-protection: 1; mode=block\r\nx-content-type-options: nosniff\r\ncontent-security-policy: default-src 'self'\r\nx-content-security-policy: default-src 'self'\r\nx-webkit-csp: default-src 'self'\r\ncache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate\r\npragma: no-cache\r\nexpires: 0\r\naccess-control-allow-origin: *\r\naccess-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS\r\nx-cache: Miss from cloudfront\r\nvia: 1.1 f7807c0a57cfa18eb5f00429067b5f6a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)\r\nx-amz-cf-pop: SYD1-C1\r\nx-amz-cf-id: gbBnOGuEFsR7_bOthF2qRpieQ-pimX133hz7z76fEaTK7xR3KWlDGg==

as you can see this string is contain : and \n\r.
my question is how i can convert this string to an object like this :

```
viResponse = {
    content-type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    content-length: "312",
    connection: "close",
    date: "Wed, 12 May 2021 08:02:40 GMT",
    server: "nginx",
    vary: "Accept-Encoding",
    x-mbx-uuid: "b2bee016-a506-46cc-9bb1-1d04eee4666f",
    x-mbx-used-weight: "81",
    x-mbx-used-weight-1m: "81",
    x-mbx-order-count-10s: "1",
    x-mbx-order-count-1d: "6",
    strict-transport-security: "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains",
    x-frame-options: "SAMEORIGIN",
    x-xss-protection: "1; mode=block",
    x-content-type-options: "nosniff",
    content-security-policy: "default-src 'self'",
    x-content-security-policy: "default-src 'self'",
    x-webkit-csp: "default-src 'self'",
    cache-control: "no-cache", no-store", must-revalidate",
    pragma: "no-cache",
    expires: "0",
    access-control-allow-origin: "*",
    access-control-allow-methods: "GET", HEAD", OPTIONS",
    x-cache: "Miss from cloudfront",
    via: "1.1 f7807c0a57cfa18eb5f00429067b5f6a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
    x-amz-cf-pop: "SYD1-C1",
    x-amz-cf-id: "gbBnOGuEFsR7_bOthF2qRpieQ-pimX133hz7z76fEaTK7xR3KWlDGg==",
}
```

please note that i want to convert the mentioned string into an object that be able to reach each parameter as its key.

```
console.log(viResponse['x-mbx-uuid']);   // b2bee016-a506-46cc-9bb1-1d04eee4666f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution may look in the following way. Though every value will be a string, so if you need to receive a Number you will need to cast it manually.

```
function responseToObject(response) {
    const result = {};
    const fields = response.split("\r\n");
    for (const field of fields) {
        const [name, ...value] = field.split(":");

        result[name] = value.join(":").trim();
    }

    return result
}
```

Based on the comment added alternative realization with `reduce` method.

```
 function responseToObject(response) {
    const fields = response.split("\r\n");

    return fields.reduce((result, field) => {
        const [name, ...value] = field.split(":");

        result[name] = value.join(":").trim();
        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

The result is the same. If you want you can make it shorter.

```
 function responseToObject(response) {   
    return response.split("\r\n").reduce((result, field) => {
        const [name, ...value] = field.split(":");

        result[name] = value.join(":").trim();

        return result;
    }, {});
}
```

For example for your string it returns

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thanks, It's Work truly. But i think there is a simpler and faster way by mapping method. anybody can do this by mapping ?

Comment: @Parsika I have updated the answer to include alternative solution with `reduce` method. It is the most appropriate one. There is no way to do that with `map` method because it returns an array as a result. Speaking of speed it is hard to tell which variant is faster.

Comment: I would say that the first varian will be faster because it uses raw `for` loop and therefore there less function calls of our callbacks, but it requires testing to be sure.

Comment: thanks for your update.  your new function return error    ==>> 
        TypeError: Cannot set property 'content-length' of undefined.  <<=  
- can you please take a look at your updated function that use reduce method?

Comment: Also i must mention that your function wont tream the values. the values starting with an space. Why?

Comment: It trims the values, the screenshot is just outdated. I have fixed the TypeError.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot to show the latest result.